# How to get a stored WLAN "password" from Windows 7?

Tags: passwords, wireless-networking

I'm trying to connect to my friends wireless network, but we don't know the password (ie. network/WEP/WPA key). The WLAN is secured by WPA2.

My friend's laptop with Windows 7 connects automatically to the WLAN. Is there a way to get the password from his laptop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) from Nirsoft should do the trick.

However, AVG (antivirus) flags it up as spyware/adware. Not sure if it is or not but just thought you may like to know...

Comment: It isn't spyware but is likely flagged as such because allowing this program to run on a coporate system can be a security vulnerability.

Comment: This will work, but @Kaushik's answer doesn't require any extra tools.

Comment: @Grezzo I agree. Unfortunately I can't delete it since it has been accepted.

Answer (score 17):

[Reference Here](http://lallousx86.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/how-to-show-saved-windows-7-wifi-passwords/)
Here is some simple steps 
On your **wifi-icon** right click -> **Open Network and Sharing Center** -> from right tab chose **Manage Wireless network** -> a list of all devises will occur there . To whom you want to know the password right click on that and go to **properties** window and chose **Security** Tab and the Check the box of **Show Characters**. That is your password

Answer (score 16):

If you want to view the security key of a wireless network you've previously been connected to (regardless of whether you're still connected to it), you can try following commands (type into command prompt to execute):

1. First list all saved profiles

   > netsh wlan show profiles
2. Now you can view the details of a wireless network using its name instead of "ProfileName"

   > netsh wlan show profile name="ProfileName" key=clear

Note that you may want to execute the commands inside an elevated command prompt (that is, run cmd.exe with administrator privileges) in order to ensure that you have enough rights to view the networks password.

Read more about managing network profiles [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/manage-wireless-network-profiles).

This works for Windows 8 (and 10) as well.

Comment: +1 for this because I have been hitting my head against a wall until I found this. Clear, concise and spot on!

Comment: This is the actual answer.  So much misinformation out there for this issue.

Comment: This should be marked as Answer.