# How to export and import, or backup and restore WiFi passwords saved in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, wifi-driver

Adjunct to [How to get a stored WLAN “password” from Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/160451/how-to-get-a-stored-wlan-password-from-windows-7), how do I back up and restore *(in case of reinstalling the wlan adapter driver)* or transfer *(in case of switching wlan adapters or laptops)* WLAN profiles?

WirelessKeyView can export the profile data unto a text file, but not import it back.  In my case, I have 50 "saved passwords" -- too much to copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

**LastPass** can backup WLAN passwords in MacOS and Windows, but can only restore them in Windows.

- To backup, on your browser click LastPass Icon > Tools > Import From > WiFi Passwords (or Other > WiFi Passwords)
- To restore, on your browser click LastPass Icon > Tools > Export To > WiFi Passwords (or Other > WiFi Passwords)

For more details, read [their instructions](http://helpdesk.lastpass.com/getting-started/importing-and-exporting-wi-fi-passwords/).

NOTE: LastPass only backs up WLAN passwords from adapters that are still installed, i.e., only those WLANs appearing in "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Manage Wireless Networks". Therefore, BACK UP THE PASSWORDS FIRST before uninstalling the WLAN adapter device driver.

**Windows 7** itself lets you back up and restore passwords via a USB flash drive, but only one by one.

**WirelessKeyView** can retrieve the passwords and save them as a text file or in HTML, but cannot restore them.  NOTE: WirelessKeyView retrieves passwords even in those adapters you've already removed.

Answer (score 2):

As an admin, first export in the old machine:

```
netsh wlan export profile key=clear
```

Then copy the files over to the new machine and import them all:

```
FORFILES /M *.xml /C "cmd /c netsh wlan add profile @path
```

Credit: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/87f21c40-7272-40b5-bab8-ed86529d7630/export-all-wireless-network-profiles-for-new-installation-windows-7?forum=w7itproinstall

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 has a built-in feature that does this. How-To-Geek has an article on how to do that here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4081/easily-backup-import-your-wireless-network-settings-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better - Easy backup and restore of WiFi profiles from any Windows machine to another.

http://lifehacker.com/5815463/wi-fi-network-backup-manager-saves-and-restores-your-wi-fi-configuration